# How to Manage Baremetal server from Openstack

Tags: kvm-virtualization, dedicated-server, openstack

i'm using openstack for manage VMs.
Now i have bunch of dedicated servers from OVH. i would like to manage entire server from openstack(for os reinstall,snapshot,firewall...etc).
**Openstack ironic** isn't suitable(i've only ssh access).

Can i use single large VM on KVM hypervisor(each dedicated server)?
or any other solution?

Comment: how about ansible ?
http://docs.openstack.org/developer/openstack-ansible/install-guide/

Comment: if all you have is ssh access, it will not work. You need more, if you want to manage those hosted machines as nova hosts